# multiprocess program in C - no output

Tags: c, multiprocessing

This is my first attempt at a C program (I'm a Java programmer).

Basically this is program that is supposed to take a positive integer, and apply the Collatz conjecture:

```
n =  
n/2, if n is even
3 × n + 1, if n is odd
```

It does this continually until n = 1.

In my program, i initialize a const int called value to 100 (representing the initial value of n), and copy that value to an int variable called newVal.

I then fork() a new process, and in the child process continually apply the Collatz conjecture while newVal is != 1, printing the new value each time it is applied. Finally when newVal does == 1, the loop ends and I print the value one last time.

Only, nothing prints at all. I don't get any errors (I am writing this on a server using putty, no IDE), just no output at all. My code:

```
int main()
{

  const int value = 100;

  pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) { /* child process */

  while (value != 1){

    if(!value%2){ 
    value = value/2;
    }

    if(value%2){ 
    value = (value*3)+1;
    }
    printf("%d", value);
  }

  printf("%d", value); 


  }

  else if (pid > 0) { 
  exit(0);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Check your precendence:  if(!newVal%2)  probably doesn't do what you mean.  If you don't have a debugger, put prints on each step to see what is happening.

Comment: I actually tried placing in prints, including printing newVal right after i initialize it, and still nothing.

Comment: You may have disproven the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a `fork`?  You could just as easily do this in the main thread.

Comment: Learning the language, trying to get the idea behind multiprocessing.

Comment: Maybe make sure the logic is right in a single threaded program  first.  Part of debugging effectively is narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `newval` is 2 at the top of the loop, it will be 4 at the next loop.
You need an `else` before the 2nd `if`.   Or, just replace the 2nd `if` with an `else` - both cases can't be true for the same value.